# What is the correct way to log in with facebook on firebase? swift

Tags: swift, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, logout

When I log in with a facebook account in a view, I pass it a second view, in the second view I want a fetch query but in the view log I get **permission denied** and I dont see the info.

I have a normal firebase account, application **test** facebook.

this is the code view log in

```
@IBAction func InicioSesionFacebook(_ sender: Any)
{
    esperaSesion.isHidden = false
    esperaSesion.startAnimating()
    let fbLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

    fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email"], from: self) { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Failed to login: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            self.esperaSesion.stopAnimating()
            return
        }

        guard let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current() else {
            print("Failed to get access token")
            self.esperaSesion.stopAnimating()
            return
        }

        let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: accessToken.tokenString)

        // Perform login by calling Firebase APIs
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
            if let error = error
            {

                self.esperaSesion.stopAnimating()
                print("Login error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Login Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let okayAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(okayAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                return
            }

            else
            {
                let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result!
                if (result?.isCancelled)!
                {
                    return
                }
                else
                {
                    // Present the main view
                    self.esperaSesion.stopAnimating()
                    if let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationMasterController")
                    {
                        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController
                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }


        })

    }
}
```

this is the code in the second view, a query

```
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FBSDKLoginKit

var refDB: DatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    refDB = Database.database().reference()
    CerrarSesion.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    imagenPerfil.layer.cornerRadius = imagenPerfil.frame.height/2
    imagenPerfil.clipsToBounds = true
    verDatos()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func verDatos()
{
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    refDB.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let nombre = value?["nombre"] as? String ?? ""
        let apellido = value?["apellido"] as? String ?? ""
        self.nombreUsuario.text = nombre
        self.apellidoUsuario.text = apellido

        // ...
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

and the button log out

```
@IBAction func CerrarSesion(_ sender: Any)
{
    do
    {

        try Auth.auth().signOut()

        self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: borrarUserDefaults)


    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        print (error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

how is the correct form for log out when I logged in with facebook account?

Comment: What exactly is your question? (your title says login, in the question you say permission denied, at the end its about logout)

Answer (score 1):

You can check out my YouTube Tutorial on this exact topic !

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BfwNf-W-R4U

The version of the Facebook API that you are using is dated. The Login function should look something like this

```
        let loginManager = LoginManager()
        loginManager.logIn(readPermissions: [.publicProfile], viewController: self) {loginResult in
            switch loginResult {
            case .failed(let error):
                print("error: \(error)")
            case .cancelled:
                print("User cancelled login.")
            case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
                print(grantedPermissions)
                print(declinedPermissions)
                fbAccessToken = accessToken
                let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: (fbAccessToken?.authenticationToken)!)
                Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error)
                        return
                    }
                    currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
                    moveToHomeScreen()
                    print("Logged in!")
                }
            }
        }
```

I think that you are getting a permissions error because the parameter name from the AccessToken changed and you are passing the wrong value. (Sorry I cant recall what the change was).

If you are following the Facebook API instructions on the facebook developer portal they are horrendously out of date iOS 9 I think.

Comment: hello, i already log in now, but do not let me make a query: it says denial of permission, in the other views do I have to put some code to share the key of session facebook? or how i make a code a query with facebook session?